# MongoDB count query performance

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have problem with count performance in MongoDB.

I'm using ZF2 and Doctrine ODM with SoftDelete filter. Now when query "first time" collection with `db.getCollection('order').count({"deletedAt": null})`, it takes about 30 seconds, sometimes even more. Second and more query takes about 150ms. After few minutes query takes again about 30 seconds. This is only on collections with size > 700MB.

Server is Amazon EC2 t2.medium instance, Mongo 3.0.1

Maybe it similar to [MongoDB preload documents into RAM for better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374342/mongodb-preload-documents-into-ram-for-better-performance), but those answers do not solve my problem.

Any ideas what is going on?

/edit

explain

```
{
"executionSuccess" : true,
"nReturned" : 111449,
"executionTimeMillis" : 24966,
"totalKeysExamined" : 0,
"totalDocsExamined" : 111449,
"executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : []
    },
    "nReturned" : 111449,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 281,
    "works" : 145111,
    "advanced" : 111449,
    "needTime" : 1,
    "needFetch" : 33660,
    "saveState" : 33660,
    "restoreState" : 33660,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "docsExamined" : 111449
},
"allPlansExecution" : []
}
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `deletedAt` field? What is the number of documents in the collection?

Comment: I have index, count is > 110k

Comment: Please shows us result of explain.  On mongos shell, execute `db.order.explain("executionStats").find()`

Comment: added explain results

Comment: if there is some activity on there, mongo will lock the count until it can get an accurate result.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23017

Answer (score 0):

The count will go through each document which is creating performance issues.

Care about the precise number if it's a small one. You're interested to know if there are 100 results or 500. But once it goes beyond, let's say, 10000, you can just say **'More than 10000 results'** found to the user.

```
db.getCollection('order').find({"deletedAt": null}).limit(10000).count(true)
```