# Insert in IDictionary of custom type using MongoDB C# driver v2.0.1

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-.net-driver

We have a class which contains some propeties including a IDictionary of custom type. When we are trying to push on that IDictionary we are getting Status as "Faulted" and a exception message which says "The serializer for field 'DataUpdates' must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info."

But on the previous version of the driver that same code was working. Here is my sample code

```
TestClass1.cs

public virtual string Id { get; set; }

[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)]
public IDictionary<Metadata, DateTime> DataUpdates { get; set; }


 Metadata.cs

 public string Collection { get; set; }

 public string Source { get; set; }

 public string Type { get; set; }
```

Here is my Update block

```
var resultMetaData = collection.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<TestClass1>.Filter.Eq(m => m.Id, someID), Builders<TestClass1>.Update.Push("DataUpdates", bsonValue));
```

and the type of the bsonValuse is something like

```
{[{ "Collection" : "TestCollection", "Source" : "TestSource", "Type" : "TestType" }, 2015-06-25T02:51:28.507Z]}
```

How can I push a new bsonValue on DataUpdates? if we really need to implement the IBsonArraySerializer, then how can we implement that serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ToBsonDocument() to convert some class object to BsonValue

Is your dictionaries are your entities. Meaning, instead of created an object to hold properties, you dump them into a Dictionary ??

you can check two relevant links:

```
MongoDB and C# Dictionary Serialisation, Part 1 – The Problem
```

http://www.danharman.net/2011/09/14/mongodb-and-c-dictionary-serialisation-part-1-the-problem/

```
How to query a sub document collection using MongoDB and C# driver
```

[How to query/update sub document in MongoDB using C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372309/how-to-query-update-sub-document-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver)